# Linear - Algebra - Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the value of b that would guarantee that the below linear system is consistent.

$$\eqalign{x_1 − 2x_2 − 6x_3  &=  -4\cr
5x_1 − 4x_2 − 2x_3  &=  -7\cr
−11x_1 + 4x_2 − 18x_3  &=  b\cr}$$

I did the row reductions and ended up with ( $0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = -2+b$ ) for the last row. So the answer I got was $b=2$, but that answer was incorrect?

---

[ 1 -2  -6 | -4 ]

[ 5 -4 -2 | -7 ]

[ -11 4 -18 | b ]

---

[ 1 -2 -6 | -4 ]

[ 0 -6 -28 | -14 ]

[ -11 4 -18 | b ]

---

[ 1 -2 -6 | -4 ]

[ 0 -6 -28 | -14 ]

[ 0 -18 -84 | -44+b]

---

[ 1 -2 -6 | -4 ]

[ 0 -6 -28 | -14 ]

[ 0 0 0 | -2+b ]

Comment: Check your row operations for arithmetic mistakes. Post them, if you can't find a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By basic passages you can transform this linear system to 
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-2 &-6 \\
0 &6 &28 \\
0 &-6 &-28 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-4\\
13\\
b-18\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-2 &-6 \\
0 &6 &28 \\
0 &0 &0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-4\\
13\\
b-5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

As you see the coefficient matrix is singular, with rank 2.

So to ensure consistency we need $b=5$.